# convert element in a list in chars

Tags: python

list is

```
l=[i for i in range(65,91)]
```

I want to convert the element to its corresponding char if and only if the element is divisible by 2.

Getting output as ,
['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J', 'L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T', 'V', 'X', 'Z']

Want output as ,

```
[65, 'B', 67, 'D', 69, 'F'...]
```

How can i do this using list comphrension ?

My code is.

```
>>>  l=[chr(i) for i in range(65,91)]
>>> new=[chr(i) for i in l if i%2==0]
>>> new
['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J', 'L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T', 'V', 'X', 'Z']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> L = [i for i in range(65, 91)]  # or just L = range(65, 91)
>>> L[1::2] = [chr(x) for x in L[1::2]]
>>> L
[65, 'B', 67, 'D', 69, 'F', 71, 'H', 73, 'J', 75, 'L', 77, 'N', 79, 'P', 81, 'R', 83, 'T', 85, 'V', 87, 'X', 89, 'Z']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your code to:

```
new = [chr(i) if i%2==0 else i for i in range(65,91)]    #you don't even need the l list anymore

>>> print new
[65, 'B', 67, 'D', 69, 'F', 71, 'H', 73, 'J', 75, 'L', 77, 'N', 79, 'P', 81, 'R', 83, 'T', 85, 'V', 87, 'X', 89, 'Z']
```

Comment: @Nishant, And the one before this as well? Thanks